# Querytext: blank value for a property

Tags: search, rest, query

How could I specify in a Querytext that I want all the elements that doesn't have defined a value for a property?

For example, let's say that I'm interested in the property CheckoutUserOWSUSER, how can I search all the documents where that property is empty?

I'm thinking on maybe: (CheckoutUserOWSUSER:"") but I think is not a correct query

Comment: I'm using REST api

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well I've found a solution, not very friendly but works, is based on [this article](http://www.itunity.com/article/filter-empty-values-search-693)

So basically the article says that you need to identify in the query how to include everything that has any value:

Text values consist of alphabetical characters (a..z) and numerical characters (0..9) and use a NOT at the beginning to exclude all the possible values... 
The "good new" is SharePoint isn't case sensitive so you have to do it only once per letter, examples:

If you want to filter, let's say by CheckoutUserOWSUSER as in the original question, by an empty value you have to include this in your querytext:

```
NOT(CheckoutUserOWSUSER:a* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:b* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:c* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:d* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:e* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:f* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:g* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:h* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:i* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:j* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:k* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:l* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:m* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:n* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:o* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:p* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:q* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:r* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:s* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:t* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:u* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:v* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:w* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:x* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:y* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:z* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:1* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:2* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:3* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:4* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:5* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:6* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:7* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:8* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:9* OR CheckoutUserOWSUSER:0*)
```

So now you are sure that you exclude all the possible values for that field and voilá.

Long and no friendly, so if you have another idea please hit it =)

Comment: I came to know to below thread and one of the comment I see -PropertyName:("*").  Will this work?
 https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/systemcenter/en-US/347d5914-b48d-4dbd-87eb-23b6342e7336/kql-query-sharepoint-2013-search-filter-by-empty-date-value?forum=sharepointsearch

Answer (score 2):

CAML Queries do support checking for Null values (unlike the REST api) and you can use CAML in REST. So you can do something like this:

```
http://somesharepointsite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('yourlist')/getitems(query=@v1)?@v1={"ViewXml":"<View><Query><Where><IsNull><FieldRef Name='CheckoutUserOWSUSER'/></IsNull></Where></View>"}
```

[Inspired by this blog.](https://twominutetip.wordpress.com/2015/03/20/sharepoint-2013-rest-api-odata-filters-no-literal-null/)