# How do I add a refinementFilter to remove results with null in certain fields?

Tags: sharepoint-online, jsom, refiner, keywordquery

I am trying to filter results from a JSOM KeywordQuery people search to only include people who have a "Department" listed, but it's still returning everyone, with and without departments.

I think I understand how to filter out an actual string, but how do I search for and filter out "null" values?

```
    var keywordQuery = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.KeywordQuery(context);
    var searchExecutor = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.SearchExecutor(context);

    keywordQuery.set_queryText('*');

    var properties = keywordQuery.get_selectProperties();
    properties.add('Department');


    var filters = keywordQuery.get_refinementFilters();
    filters.add('Department<>"null"');
```

Answer (score 0):

The proposed solution here uses query syntax to achieve that: [Querytext: blank value for a property](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/149012/querytext-blank-value-for-a-property)

This is the only way I am aware of accomplishing this. I don't think there is a way of doing that with refinement filters