# What search syntax can be used to return results where a user profile field is empty?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, modern-experience, user-profile-property

Working with SharePoint Modern and user profiles that have with category fields to populate with topics of interest.

I've set up a search results page for "pages for me" that refines results automatically, based on the value/s the user select/s for their 'business area', 'product' and other (4) categories that they're interested in.

...AND {|Refinablestring123:{User.BusinessArea}} AND {|Refinablestring123:{User.Product}}...etc

This works fine, and returns results whether the user has selected one or a number of values in each category.

The problem arises when the user leaves the category field blank, either because they want to see *all* topics in that category, or that category is not relevant to them. The search results are empty due to the vacant field.

Is there a way to treat a blank category as "all values"?

Comment: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/149012/querytext-blank-value-for-a-property

Comment: That is a recipe for errors, eh? There must be a better way. Perhaps the answer is to create a 'none' value in the termset that a user selects if no topics is relevant, and that is added to pages where terms aren't relevant in that category...